# Docker image with node-sass on arm processor

Tags: npm, node-sass

I'm building my CI on gitlab and one of the jobs I need to execute is to  compile sass stylesheets.

In order to compile sass I'm using node-sass which when installed needs to be compiled from source.

In order NOT to compile every time node-sass from source, I created a docker image with:

- node and npm
- node-sass installed globally (`npm install --unsafe-perm -g node-sass`)

In my project's package.json I kept node-sass devDependencies with the very same version of the one installed in the docker image described above.

My problem is that when I execute `npm install` (right before compiling my scss), npm tries to install node-sass again and goes through the whole compilation from source process.

How can avoid this?

One solution I thought, is to remove node-sass from the devDependencies and just add them as optionalDependencies or something, but I don't like this dirty solution.

Does anyone even know why npm tries to install node-sass anyway even though the version requested by package.json it is globally installed?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by adding node-sass to package.json as optional dependency like so:

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "4.10.0"
},
```

and now, whenever I need to skip the installation because I know there is a global version installed, I just do:

```
npm install --no-optional
```

This is kind of a work around nut it works great.